# Probability of winning a snooker-match

Tags: probability, statistics, recurrence-relations

Suppose, a snokker match is best of $2n-1$, so the player who wins $n$
frames wins the match.

Suppose, the probability for winning a frame is $p$ for player $1$.

> - What is the probability (denoted by $q(n,p)$ ) that player $1$ wins the match ?

Trivial cases are 
$$n=1\ \ \  (q(1,p)=p)$$
$$p=0\ \ \  (q(n,p)=0\ for\ all\ n)$$
$$p=1\ \ \  (q(n,p)=1\ for\ all\ n)$$
$$p=\frac{1}{2}\ \ \ (q(n,p)=\frac{1}{2}\ for\ all\ n\ due\ to\ symmetry)$$

My idea is a recursive approach : If both players have won $n-1$ frames, the
probability that player $1$ wins is $p$ and so on. But I do not know how to
do this for arbitary many frames.

Comment: You should use the binomial distribution.

Comment: it doesn't matter that it's "before", because only one player can get n wins. Basically, you can play all the 2n-1 match, and it won't change the probability of the first player winning

Comment: Not exactly n, as player 1 win if he win n+1 match too. You're looking for $P(X \geq n)$. The interesting part is to demonstrate what I said before ;)

Comment: But in the case of playing all frames out, player $1$ might win more than $n$ frames.

Comment: Yeah, but he'll win the game if he win $n$ or more frames

Comment: So, $q(n,p)=P(X\ge n)$ with $X$~$B(2n-1,p)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot.